# java scaling of a jframe

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

Is it possible to create a `JFrame` and `setResizeable(true)`, but have the x and y values scale by the same amount, i.e. you cannot increase just the x or y but both at the same time so it stays in proportion?

Answer (score 3):

Although not perfect, you could add a [ComponentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) to the JFrame, overriding specifically `ComponentListener.componentResized` -- (since that's all you need, you could just extend a [ComponentAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentAdapter.html)).

The basic gist would be:

1. Record the JFrame's initial size (either with two integers or with a [Dimension](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) object).
2. In the component resized, get the JFrame's current size
3. Set the JFrame's **new size** based on the old size with the new size (either based on which ever dimension, height or width, increased the most or least. You can play with that).
4. Record the JFrame's new size
5. Rinse and repeat.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 So, basically each time the component is resized, you adjust x and y to be the same ( width and height that is)